# Query result set randomly duplicated

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've a very simple query that returns duplicated rows, randomly. Sometimes I have no duplicates, other times I have duplicate result set, and duplicated record are every time different. I'm running the query on frozen database (data don't change). My Oracle version is the 11g.

I have only one filter (in the WHERE clause) on a date:
`to_char(date,'yyyy/mm') > = '2012/03'`.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you for your attention.
Best regards.

**Complete query**:

```
select distinct 
   B.ORD_V_COD_ROWID as c1,
   B.ORD_D_DAT_INSERITO_RIFIUTATO as c2,
   B.ORD_D_DAT_RIFIUTO_SIS as c3
  from   
       NRFTF_ORD_ORDINE A,
       NRFTF_COR_ORDINI_RDS B
  where  (A.ORD_N_DWH_NUM_ORDINE = B.ORD_N_DWH_NUM_ORDINE 
  and B.ORD_V_COD_CAUSALE = 'CLIENTE NON AFFIDABILE' 
  and B.ORD_V_COD_STATO = 'RIFIUTATO' 
  and B.RDS_C_DWH_FLG_CANCELLAZIONE = '0' 
  and B.ORD_C_DWH_FLG_CANCELLAZIONE = '0' 
  and B.ORD_V_COD_CAUSALE = 'CLIENTE NON AFFIDABILE' 
  and B.PER_NAME_MONTH >= '2012/03' 
  and (B.ORD_D_DAT_RIFIUTO_SIS >= TO_DATE('2012-03-22 00:00:00' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
  or B.ORD_D_DAT_INSERITO_RIFIUTATO >= TO_DATE('2012-03-22 00:00:00' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) 
  and  TO_CHAR (A.ord_d_dat_creazione,'YYYY/MM') >= '2012/03' ) 
  order by c1, c2, c3
```

Comment: What query? Show all query text, not the part

Comment: Edit your question to show the query (don't put it in a comment...)

Comment: B.PER_NAME_MONTH is a varchar2, right ?

Comment: Yes, B.PER_NAME_MONTH is a field stored on the table B as varchar2. I wonder if I should check on trobles on db, looking for size of SGA or something else. Thank you for your answer and attention..

Comment: what version of 11g is your database, including patchset?  Sounds like an oracle bug if you are getting duplicate result/wrong results from the query.

Comment: The version of database is 11.1.0.6.0. About the pathset, I'm looking for..

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I have seen somewhat similar behaviour with a broken index. Rebuilding the index fixed the problem for sometime, but then non deterministic behaviour came back. We ended up calling Oracle support. They fixed it in a really impressive 24hour-around-the-globe-updating-the-data-dictionary-session.

I'd try rebuilding all tables and indexes involved from scratch.

If this doesn't help and you triple checked that you don't have anything dynamic going on on your side contact Oracle support.

Comment: Thank you Jens, I'm going to rebuild involved indexes, hoping it'll work.